# J2ME app File size

Tags: java-me

i have doing j2me app using LWUIT lib.
it get nearly 600kb.
then i have use net-bean default Obfuscation tool.
but still it size is not less than 430kb.
any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your resources, they might be too large. Also make sure there aren't any hidden files in your jar file, for example make sure the Thumps.db which generated in windows is not there!

Comment: Mahdi my resources file is size 86kb.

Comment: theri is no any auto generated Thumps.db file.

Comment: my all src folder size is 172kb. but jar?

Comment: extract your jar file and check every folder to see which one causes this problem, also make sure you show the hidden files before the check.

Comment: it get 732kb for lwuit lib. igess it the reson. any way to reduce this?

Comment: put the obfuscation level to the maximum in NetBeans

Comment: did you used lwuit lib before? if how much nomly get siz your jars?

Comment: yes, I am using it for every single application I build. Normally the size between 200-400 KB which depends on my resources. Level 8 is not enough you should put it on the maximum and see what you will got.

Comment: i use maximum obfuscation level then it reduce to 200kb. then i use kjar to recompress it now size is 193kb. some of my other game reduce to 166kb. thanks for the tip.